# C++: Deleting the the fields of a struct that was declared on the stack

Tags: c++, struct, heap-memory, stack-memory

If I declare a struct such as this one:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int* nums;
};

MyStruct ms;
ms.nums = new int[4];
```

Do I need to call `delete ms.nums;` before exiting my program or will the member variable `nums` automatically get deallocated because the MyStruct instance `ms` wasn't declared on the heap?

Comment: You have to call delete[] on nums as the memory that it points to is allocated in heap

Comment: Good point you clarified your confusion, I too had same confusion in my early days with C/C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to delete that.. struct's default destructor won't do that. It will just delete the pointer variable which holds the address of the object and object will be left alone forever.

Better to do the deletion inside the struct's destructor

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int* nums;

  public :
     ~MyStruct()
      {
        if(nums != NULL)
            delete nums;
      }
};
```

Comment: Given the new[] in the question, the destructor should `delete[]`.  Trivially, deletion of a NULL pointer is a no-op, so there's no need to guard against it, but it would be a good idea to have a constructor set nums to NULL/0/nullptr.  `struct` members default to `public:`.

Comment: This is a great example of why you shouldn't usually manage dynamic resources manually, and take great care (paying attention to the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722)) when you have to. Even if you fix the incorrect form of `delete`, this class will cause undefined behaviour if you default-construct or copy it.

Answer (score 4):

The member variable `nums` (which is a pointer) will get automatically deallocated when `ms`, the struct containing it, is popped off the stack.

However, the *memory* pointed to by `nums` will NOT.  You should call `delete [] ms.nums;` before your program exits.

Answer (score 2):

You always have to call `delete` to deallocate all the memory that you explicitly allocated using `new`.

When you allocate memory using `new`, memory is allocated in heap and the base address of the block is returned back.

Your `struct` is present in stack which contains a pointer pointing to that base address. When the `struct` object leaves the scope, the object is deallocated , i.e. the pointer containig the address of allocated heap memory block is gone, but the heap memory itself is still allocated which you can't deallocate now.

Comment: And here it should be delete[]

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `delete` if memory allocated and pointer returned to `num`. Here `num` is a pointer inside a structure. Memory for `num` is allocated when you declare structure variable. But memory address which is allocated by `new` should be un-allocated by calling `delete`

Answer (score 1):

Memory for the pointer itself will be deallocated when the object is destroyed, as it is for any class member. However, the array it points to won't be deleted - there is no way to know what the pointer points to, whether it was allocated by `new` or `new[]` or not dynamically allocated at all, or whether anything else still wants to use it. To avoid memory leaks, you should delete it, with the array form `delete [] ms.nums;`, once you've finished with it.

Since it's often hard to do this correctly, why not use a library class to manage the array correctly for you?

```
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
};

MyStruct ms;
ms.nums.resize(4);
```

Now all the memory will be released automatically when `ms` is destroyed; and the class is correctly copyable and (since C++11) efficiently movable.

Answer (score 0):

The `struct` is allocated on the stack, which basically is a `pointer to an Array`. the `array is allocated on the heap`. Every time you write "new" that means that the allocation is on the heap therefore you need to `"delete"` it. On the other hand the struct will be remove as soon as you exit the function.

Answer (score 0):

When program exit, OS will free all memory allocated by your program. 
On the other hand, if a memory allocation occurs multiple times during the life of the program, then surely it should be released to prevent dangling pointers.